# caps lock reassigned while upgrading 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, 20.04

I was upgrading my Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04 and during the upgrading process, i was prompted to choose a key for something that I didn't understand so i chose <kbd>caps lock</kbd> (randomly)

now I realized it was the key to change keyboard layout/input language

so now I'm stuck with lowercase as you might've noticed. <kbd>caps lock</kbd> now changes language not lowercase-uppercase.

how can I change it again? I can't find anything in the settings

*note that these are the shortcut for changing language. but <kbd>caps lock</kbd> also changes language and not the case*

[image]

Comment: As a temporary solution, to type capital letter press shift (either left or right) and then press the letter. This will print that letter in upper case. It is better to use shift rather than pressing caps lock and then the letter and then caps lock again. This saves time. Infact good typers rarely use caps lock button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install `gnome-tweaks` for this. Run `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks` in terminal to install `gnome-tweaks`.

1. Open `gnome-tweaks`, from app drawer.
2. Select `keyboard & mouse` in the left column.

[image]
3. Click on the `Additional Layout Options` and scroll down to `Switching to another layout`.

[image]

4. Uncheck the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> button, and select a button, if you wish to assign any, and you are good to go.